# Make user select one friend and pull that friend's profile photo in Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an app where I ask the user to select one friend from his friend list, and then I want to get the friend's profile photo with php.

I have all the necessary permissions set. I require a breakdown of how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the user's friends with **Graph API**: `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/friends` and display them.
2. Let the user make a choice and keep the ID of the friend he selected.
3. Display his profile picture with the desired size: `https://graph.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID?fields=picture.height(720)`

**Little trick:** you'll get the max size by choosing more than 960 pixels as the height.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. It obviously makes sense. I just haev an issue on the "Let the user make a choice and keep the ID of the friend he selected" part. What will be the suggested practice considering I'm using php?

Comment: For each friends, generate a link that contains the id (i.e. `yoursite.com/showpicture.php?id=123456789`). When you click on the link, it redirects you to the PHP script that displays the profile picture.

Answer (score 2):

1. For the friend selector, you can use any "multi-friend selector" plugin available. I used [mikebrevoort's](http://archives-mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html) plugin in one of my app.
2. This will return the ID's of the selected friends.
3. Get the profile picture using:

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/SELECTED_ID/picture?type=TYPE
   (TYPE: small/normal/large/square)
   ```

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded the files, but the video on Vimeo is not playing. Also, when I check the example I get the login error message. Is there any ways I could get a proper documentation non how to use this plugin? Thank you.

Comment: I already used this one and work pretty well! https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector